# Equivalent command of "audioplayer" and "play" from MATLAB in python?

Tags: python, matlab, signal-processing

How can I write this same code from MATLAB in Python? what modules should I use?

```
player = audioplayer(y, Fs);
play(player);
% y = Audio signal represented by a vector or two-dimensional array containing
%single, double, int8, uint8, or int16 values.
%Fs = Sampling rate in Hz
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`simpleaudio`](https://simpleaudio.readthedocs.io) package allows audio playback of [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/) vectors with time-domain signals.

Here is a simple usage example taken from the simpleaudio package's [documentation](https://simpleaudio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#using-numpy):

```
import numpy as np
import simpleaudio as sa

# calculate note frequencies
A_freq = 440
Csh_freq = A_freq * 2 ** (4 / 12)
E_freq = A_freq * 2 ** (7 / 12)

# get timesteps for each sample, T is note duration in seconds
sample_rate = 44100
T = 0.25
t = np.linspace(0, T, T * sample_rate, False)

# generate sine wave notes
A_note = np.sin(A_freq * t * 2 * np.pi)
Csh_note = np.sin(Csh_freq * t * 2 * np.pi)
E_note = np.sin(E_freq * t * 2 * np.pi)

# concatenate notes
audio = np.hstack((A_note, Csh_note, E_note))
# normalize to 16-bit range
audio *= 32767 / np.max(np.abs(audio))
# convert to 16-bit data
audio = audio.astype(np.int16)

# start playback
play_obj = sa.play_buffer(audio, 1, 2, sample_rate)

# wait for playback to finish before exiting
play_obj.wait_done()
```